# Error Installation Aircrack-ng 1.2RC libnl-3-dev

Tags: 13.04, aircrack-ng

first before installing aircrack-ng i run:

```
sudo apt-get install libnl-3-dev
sudo apt-get build-dep aircrack-ng
```

i downloaded the aircrack-ng 1.2 rc 1 from the aircrack web.

when i try to make i get the next error: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnl-genl-3`

i did have a look at the :

```
dpkg -l | grep libnl
libnl-3-200:amd64                         3.2.16-0ubuntu1   
libnl-3-dev                               3.2.16-0ubuntu1        
libnl-genl-3-200:amd64                    3.2.16-0ubuntu1             
libnl-route-3-200:amd64                   3.2.16-0ubuntu1             
libnl1:amd64                              1.1-8ubuntu1
```

so whats wrong? eitherway i couldnt find /usr/bin/libnl or whatever but there is /etc/libnl-3

here is the verbose from make

---

make -C src all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/serdar/WIFI/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc1/src'
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude   -c -o aircrack-ng.o aircrack-ng.c
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude   -c -o crypto.o crypto.c
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude   -c -o common.o common.c
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude   -c -o uniqueiv.o uniqueiv.c
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude   -c -o aircrack-ptw-lib.o aircrack-ptw-lib.c
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude  aircrack-ng.o crypto.o common.o uniqueiv.o aircrack-ptw-lib.o sha1-sse2.S -o aircrack-ng -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto

gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude   -c -o airdecap-ng.o airdecap-ng.c
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude  airdecap-ng.o crypto.o common.o -o airdecap-ng -lssl -lcrypto 
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude   -c -o packetforge-ng.o packetforge-ng.c
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude  packetforge-ng.o common.o crypto.o -o packetforge-ng -lssl -lcrypto 
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude   -c -o ivstools.o ivstools.c
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude  ivstools.o common.o crypto.o uniqueiv.o -o ivstools -lssl -lcrypto 
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude   -c -o kstats.o kstats.c
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude  kstats.o -o kstats 
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude   -c -o makeivs-ng.o makeivs-ng.c
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude  makeivs-ng.o common.o uniqueiv.o -o makeivs-ng 
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude   -c -o airdecloak-ng.o airdecloak-ng.c
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude   -c -o osdep/radiotap/radiotap.o osdep/radiotap/radiotap.c
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude  airdecloak-ng.o common.o osdep/radiotap/radiotap.o -o airdecloak-ng 
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude   -c -o wpaclean.o wpaclean.c
make -C osdep
make[2]: Entering directory`/home/serdar/WIFI/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc1/src/osdep'
Building for Linux
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/serdar/WIFI/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc1/src/osdep'
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -fPIC -I..    -c -o osdep.o osdep.c
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -fPIC -I..    -c -o network.o network.c
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -fPIC -I..    -c -o file.o file.c
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -fPIC -I..    -c -o linux.o linux.c
linux.c: In function ‘error_handler’:
linux.c:373:46: warning: unused parameter ‘nla’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 static int error_handler(struct sockaddr_nl *nla, struct nlmsgerr *err,
                                              ^
linux.c: In function ‘test_callback’:
linux.c:382:42: warning: unused parameter ‘msg’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 static void test_callback(struct nl_msg *msg, void *arg)
                                          ^
linux.c:382:53: warning: unused parameter ‘arg’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 static void test_callback(struct nl_msg *msg, void *arg)
                                                     ^
linux.c: In function ‘linux_set_channel_nl80211’:
linux.c:1030:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘if_nametoindex’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     devid=if_nametoindex(wi->wi_interface);
     ^
linux.c:955:18: warning: unused variable ‘wrq’ [-Wunused-variable]
     struct iwreq wrq;
                  ^
linux.c: At top level:
linux.c:373:12: warning: ‘error_handler’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int error_handler(struct sockaddr_nl *nla, struct nlmsgerr *err,
            ^
linux.c:382:13: warning: ‘test_callback’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static void test_callback(struct nl_msg *msg, void *arg)
             ^
linux.c:1067:12: warning: ‘linux_set_channel’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int linux_set_channel(struct wif *wi, int channel)
            ^
linux.c:2066:13: warning: ‘linux_close’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static void linux_close(struct wif *wi)
             ^
linux.c: In function ‘do_linux_open.constprop.1’:
linux.c:184:14: warning: ‘iwpriv’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
         execl(path, "iwpriv",iface, "ndis_reset", NULL);
              ^
linux.c:1620:11: note: ‘iwpriv’ was declared here
     char *iwpriv;
           ^
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -fPIC -I..    -c -o linux_tap.o linux_tap.c
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -fPIC -I..    -c -o common.o common.c
ar cru libosdep.a  osdep.o network.o file.o linux.o linux_tap.o radiotap/radiotap.o common.o
ranlib libosdep.a 
touch .os.Linux
make[3]: Leaving directory`/home/serdar/WIFI/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc1/src/osdep'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/serdar/WIFI/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc1/src/osdep'
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude  wpaclean.o osdep/radiotap/radiotap.o -o wpaclean -Losdep -losdep -lnl-genl-3 -lnl-3

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnl-genl-3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [wpaclean] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/serdar/WIFI/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc1/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2

---

Answer (score 1):

It was missing `apt-get install libnl-genl-3-dev`